# Miniconda: issue with shell configuration/initialization

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I installed miniconda on our CentOS cluster and it all went fine. Then I asked miniconda to create a python 3.8 environment, and it went fine. However, when I try to activate the environment, I get the following error:

```
CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.
To initialize your shell, run

$ conda init <SHELL_NAME>
```

I verified, and it's a `bash` environment. So I ran `conda init bash` and I got the following outputs:

```
no change     /MyPath/miniconda3/condabin/conda
no change     /MyPath/miniconda3/bin/conda
no change     /MyPath/miniconda3/bin/conda-env
no change     /MyPath/miniconda3/bin/activate
no change     /MyPath/miniconda3/bin/deactivate
no change     /MyPath/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
no change     /MyPath/miniconda3/etc/fish/conf.d/conda.fish
no change     /MyPath/miniconda3/shell/condabin/Conda.psm1
no change     /MyPath/miniconda3/shell/condabin/conda-hook.ps1
no change     /MyPath/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xontrib/conda.xsh
no change     /MyPath/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.csh
no change     /home/users/me/.bashrc
No action taken.
```

So nothing happens. And when I try to activate the new environment, then I still get the first error.

Any idea how I can fix this?

[Solution] Thanks to the answer below, the issue was that despite testing that I was running/using a bash, I still have to run "bash" in the command line before activating model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried manually adding to `~/.bashrc`?

- add `export PATH="/home/username/miniconda/bin:$PATH"` in your bashrc file. make sure to replace `/home/username/miniconda` with your actual path now save the file, quit and reopen the terminal should work I guess.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already did all that before posting, still does not work.

Comment: If you have the PATH in your .bashrc file and are still getting errors. Your terminal might not be looking for the bash file. Type `bash` in the terminal to ensure you are in bash and then try: `conda --version`

Comment: Thank you. Despite I checked if I was in a bash and the answer was yes, running just "bash" helped.

Comment: ciao mate! glad it helped you 